# use of varargin in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, variables, input

I have a function contains input arguments as `var1` to `var5`, I want to use `varargin` in order to user-defined input arguments, how can I assing `var1` to `var5` to input arguments?
I tried, but this gives error as **undeifned function or variable var1**.
How if I want to skip `var2` when calling a function?
**My code:**

```
function  out= myFunc(varargin)
varargin{1} = var1;
varargin{2} = var2;
varargin{3} = var3;
varargin{4} = var4;
varargin{5} = var5;
%operations on var1,var2,var3,var4 and var5 like
var1 == 'variable1';
end
```

Comment: Think you are doing the other way. It must be - `var1 = varargin{1};`, `var2 = varargin{2};` and so on. Want to skip assigning to `var2`? Just skip it. `varargin` gives you the list of inputs to a function. Reassigning values to it, doesn't make a normal scenario, nothing stopping you do that though.

Comment: if I skip var2, and enter var3, then what would the effect on  `var2 = varargin{2};` ?

Comment: Code for you - `function out= myFunc(varargin)

var1 = varargin{1};
var3 = varargin{3};
var4 = varargin{4};
var5 = varargin{5};

%%// Do something with var1, var3, var4, var5

return;`

Comment: what about var2? if it is defined or if it is not defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variable you are assigning to on the left hand of the `=` sign, not the right.

You can also use the colon operator on a cell array to do multiple assignment via a comma-separated list, if you know you'll aways get at least that many arguments passed to this function.

```
[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5] = varargin{1:5};
```

If you know you'll have exactly five arguments, you can just use `:` when indexing in to the argument list.

```
[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5] = varargin{:};
```

And if you're uninterested in a particular input argument, you can either omit it from the list of indexes on the right hand side, or use `~` as a placeholder on the left hand side to discard it. Let's say you only care about inputs 1, 3, and 4, and want to toss inputs 2 and 5. You can do either of these.

```
[var1, var3, var4] = varargin{[1 3 4]};
[var1, ~, var3, var4, ~] = varargin{1:5};
```

Comment: Ur solution seems impressive enough, Please tell more if to skip an argument during function call, is there any way to do so ?